# values are not returning from html for flask getlist

Tags: python, html, flask, request, flask-restful

so this is my HTML where I select a multi drop input

```
<form method="POST">
<a><select  name="for_x" class="selectpicker"  method="POST"  multiple data-live-search="true" >
 {% for cols in list_cols %}
    <option value= "{{cols}}" SELECTED>{{cols}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
    </select></a>
<a><p>Please select X variables</p></a>

#html code for button type=submit ,value etc input here

</form>
```

values aren't being sent to flask code

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        x=request.form.getlist('for_x[]')
```

I can't return the x values even after selecting them on the html

Answer (score -1):

Do these changes,
HTML

form method='POST' `action=flask function name`

select class="selectpicker" name="for_x" multiple data-live-search="true"

**Flask**
if request.method == 'POST':
x=request.form.getlist('for_x')

If you use '[]' in name in select tag then you need to keep it as it is in form.getlist as well.

Comment: ERROR in app: Exception on /feature_selection/<filename>,        and also File /tmp/<filename> does not exist: '/tmp/<filename>'  these are the errors I get